# Magento 2 add /home to homepage url only

Tags: magento2

I have tried to add custom url rewrite from Magento 2 admin with

- `Request Path = /`
- `Target Path = home`
- `Redirect Type = 301 Permanent`

So when user visit the homepage, url will be 'baseurl/home'

With this solution, there is cache issue with homepage as at first, baseurl will be loaded and again redirected to baseurl/home so first landing will skip the cache hence homepage is slow.

So how we can add /home to baseurl for homepage only without any redirection?

Answer (score 0):

1) In database Search the ***core_config_data***

2) Change the ***web/unsecure/base_url*** In add value ***http://127.0.0.1/homagepage/*** 
as to same to ***web/secure/base_url***

3) And command in terminals ***rm -rf var/cache***